# Inter-rater reliability for two raters, multiple binary codes

Tags: binary-data, agreement-statistics

I have two raters who utilized a binary codebook with codes (A, B, C) to code a series of responses. The codes are not independent, and a response could have more than one code (or no codes at all). Such as:

```
Rater 1:
             A B C
response 1   1 0 0
response 2   0 1 1
response 3   0 1 0
...

Rater 2:
             A B C
response 1   0 0 0
response 2   0 0 1
response 3   0 1 1
...
```

Is there a preferred method for calculating inter-rater reliability for the **set of codes**, rather than each code individually? I can compute separate Kappas for A, B, C, but this doesn't seem correct since they are not independent ratings.

Apologies if this has been answered before.