# How do you calculate interrater reliability for multiple items?

Tags: binary-data, psychometrics, measurement, agreement-statistics

I have responses rated on 12 binary categories, treating the categories as separate items on the same measure. There are 10 raters, so Fleiss's Kappa seems appropriate. How would you compute reliability for the whole measure? Would you calculate it for each individual item and then take the average of all coefficients as the overall reliability?

So for instance I have 5 responses and code them on categories A, B, and C. I would compute Kappa separately for each category, but then how to summarize the reliability across categories? Credit to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167740/inter-rater-reliability-for-two-raters-multiple-binary-codes) for the sample data structure.

```
Rater 1:
              A B C         
Response 1 |  1 0 1
Response 2 |  1 0 0
Response 3 |  0 0 1
Response 4 |  1 1 0
Response 5 |  0 1 0

Rater 2:
              A B C         
Response 1 |  1 0 1
Response 2 |  1 0 0
Response 3 |  0 0 1
Response 4 |  1 1 0
Response 5 |  0 1 0

Rater 3:
              A B C         
Response 1 |  1 0 0
Response 2 |  0 1 0
Response 3 |  1 0 1
Response 4 |  1 0 0
Response 5 |  1 1 1
```

This seems very straightforward, yet all examples I've found are for one specific rating, e.g. inter-rater reliability for one of the binary codes.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167740/inter-rater-reliability-for-two-raters-multiple-binary-codes) and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240750/inter-rater-reliability-for-multiple-categorial-variables-and-two-raters) ask essentially the same thing, but there doesn't seem to be a conclusion.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm not sure I understand how Cronbach's alpha would be used here.

Comment: Are these 12 categories combined in some way? (I'm having trouble visualizing the problem - example data would help me.)

Comment: Yes, this is part of a qualitative data analysis where each response could be mapped onto 12 different "themes" or categories. So a response could be coded as matching one, some, or zero of the themes. Example data added above.

Comment: Are the 12 themes combined to get some sort of total score? If not, I"m not sure that overall reliability is a useful thing to know.

Comment: In that sense no, they will not be combined. Ok, makes sense to stick with reporting Kappa for each theme. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @votmoyd Have you ever figured this out? I decided to go with Kappa and Krippendorff for each theme but not sure if you've found a better way!

Comment: @CatMai I reported them individually, and used that method ever since. I'd be interested to hear from someone who does a lot of IRR for qualitative data though.